# Emgu CV check web cam connectivity

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am writing a C# web camera application using Emgu CV. I tried to handle when user unplug the web cam during frame capturing in pictureBox.
If the web camera is unplugged, then the application should start scanning for new web cam connectivity every 2 seconds until the pictureBox can be updated again.
The following timer code could not catch anything, the program initially captures frames, I unplug the camera, then plug back, but the camera can not be restart.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (cap == null)
        {
            try
            {
                cap = new Capture(0);
                cap.SetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
                cap.SetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);

                Console.WriteLine("Restarting Cam");
            }
            catch (Exception ee){ 
                Console.WriteLine("null"); cap = null;  return; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NO null");
        }

        try
        {
            Image<Bgr, byte> nextFrame = cap.QueryFrame();
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Frame Capture fail");
            cap.Dispose();
            cap = null;
            return;
        }
        using (Image<Bgr, byte> nextFrame = cap.QueryFrame())
        {
            if (nextFrame != null)
            {
                Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = nextFrame.Convert<Gray, byte>();
                videoBox.Image = nextFrame.ToBitmap();
            }
        }
    }
```

The program keep printing "No null", 20 second after unplugging the camera, the output console printed out The thread '' (0xb96c) has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Answer (score 0):

You can check connectivity with DirectShow lib. Get an array of all connected cameras first

```
DirectShowLib.DsDevice[] allCameras = DirectShowLib.DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
```

add to you class property for selected camera name, and then you can check if camera is connected

```
bool isConnected = DirectShowLib.DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice).Any(c => c.Name == selectedCameraName);
```